# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '4'

Tags: python, deep-learning, word2vec

How to fix this? I already train the model.

Code:

```
#embedding
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

word_vectors = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("w2v02_wiki_sg.model")

EMBEDDING_DIM = 300
vocabulary_size= jumlah_index
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocabulary_size, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in t.word_index.items():
  try:
    embedding_vector = word_vectors[word]
    embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
  except KeyError:
    embedding_matrix[i]=np.random.normal(0,np.sqrt(0.25),EMBEDDING_DIM)

del(word_vectors)
from keras.layers import Embedding
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            trainable=True)
```

Error:

```
INFO:gensim.utils:loading Word2Vec object from w2v02_wiki_sg.model
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-84edc08f9bfb> in <module>
      7 from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
      8 
----> 9 word_vectors = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("w2v02_wiki_sg.model")
     10 
     11 EMBEDDING_DIM = 300

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/utils.py in unpickle(fname)
   1359         # Because of loading from S3 load can't be used (missing readline in smart_open)
   1360         if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
-> 1361             return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
   1362         else:
   1363             return _pickle.loads(f.read())

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '4'.
```

Comment: did you save it using the same Python? Different versions of Python can write pickle in different way and you can't read it with different version.

Comment: command [save](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2VecTrainables.save) has option `pickle_protocol=4` and maybe you should save it with lower value.

Comment: Or alternatively, make sure the Python & Gensim versions where you're trying to `.load()` the model match those that were used where the model was 1st trained & saved. (Models will often smoothly load into *later* versions, but all-bets-are-off if you try to take something saved from later versions and load it into older configurations.) If this doesn't help, you should expand your question to include more details about the origin of the model – how it was trained, with what software versions – and the destination where you're trying the `.load()`.

Comment: (And further, because the `.loas()` itself is enough to trigger the error, you could delete all your code after that line as superfluous with regard to reproducing/undersstanding the error. Instead, it would be more helpful to answerers to ensure your report of the error includes *all* involved traceback frames. It looks like something in your config may have changed to hide some of them – but they're all potentially helpful when things go wrong & you need others to help get over a problem.)